# How to convert code of an android app to symbian

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, symbian

i develope an app for android ad i have to create the same app for symbian and Window phone. Is there a way to convert the code due to rewrite from start the same app? Thanks!

Comment: There might be some converters developed by enthusiasts, but i have never heard of any professional one, and if there would be any, it does not mean that you can just load your code and get a pretty nice version of another application as an output. Creating this kind of translators is increadibly difficult

Comment: Ok, but i can modify the "source" generated to make it professional

Comment: Good modification takes usually more time than creation. To save your time drastically without learning every OS cenventions, consider PhoneGap(combination of html, js - http://phonegap.com/start/) or a Web App

Comment: just to clarify are u interested in just porting android ad sdk to symbian?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no tool to convert existing app. If you are starting from scratch you can use [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)

**EDIT:**

> PhoneGap is an HTML5 app platform that allows you to author native
>   applications with web technologies that can run on multiple
>   platforms(symban, iOs,android, windows)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't, See any other tools like, [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) if possible. But I don't think so it (Any tool if available) help you totally, means the chances of complete conversion as we want is less.

EDIT:

```
PhoneGap is an HTML5 app platform that allows you to author native applications with web
technologies and get access to APIs and app stores. PhoneGap leverages web technologies 
developers already know best... HTML and JavaScript.
```

I think its helpful only on web application.

Comment: What is phonegap? Only a tutorial to create app for smartphone?

Comment: I saw, but i understood is Only a tutorial